# Magento 2 - setup:di:compile (general question)

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile

This is a general question about the magento 2 cli, and what the setup does. Every time i want to install or uninstall a module I have to run the following command.

```
setup:di:compile
```

What does this do? Does it take all the new modules and compile them? And what is the difference between this and:

```
setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
```

Comment: refer this - http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146496/what-i-do-if-setupdicompile-fails/146501#146501

Comment: Di compile's only use is to annoy developers and give them time to make a brew ;) I may or may not be joking.

Comment: Haha I knew it. Its all just a front. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
```

> Use this command if you have multiple tenants, which means more than
> one independent Magento application. In other words:
>
> There is one Magento 2 code base instance
>
> There is one database instance per tenant
>
> Independent configurations in the Magento Admin per tenant
>
> The storefronts are independent of each other

Source: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html

Answer (score 2):

Command `setup:di:compile` is related to Magento 2's code compiler. M2 compiles code such as **Factories, Interceptors, Proxies** etc and puts them in `var/generation` directory.

One of the reasons of code generation is performance so code is readily available for application at run time and doesn't go through process of executing interceptors etc each time a request is made.

When you uninstall a plugin it may have generated code in var/generation directory, setup:di:compile will generate new version of code so uninstalled plugin code is removed.

```
setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
```

command is used when you're using more than one independent applications under one Magento 2 code base instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
setup:di:compile
```

This command do following things

> ```
> Application code generation (factories, proxies, and so on)
> Area configuration aggregation (that is, optimized dependency injection configurations per area)
> Interceptor generation (that is, optimized code generation of interceptors)
> Interception cache generation
> Repositories code generation (that is, generated code for APIs)
> Service data attributes generation (that is, generated extension classes for data objects)
> ```

and `setup:di:compile-multi-tenant` its used for following perpose

> In Magento versions 2.0.5 and earlier, there is a known issue with the single-tenant compiler; it does not currently compile proxies. Therefore, if you're preparing to deploy to production, you must use the multi-tenant compiler.

The issue was resolved in Magento versions 2.0.6 and later.